# Standard error for lmer time variables in R

Tags: r, lme4

So, I am trying to predict the change in something (MS_TOT) over time. I have my time variable (ExamStage: 1, 3, 6 and 12 months) and my drug use variable (acstatus, a factor w three levels).  I think that the drug use will affect this change as an interaction w time, which I put in my lmer model (ignore other variables):

```
    >model6<-lmer(MS_TOT~acstatus+ExamStage+acstatus*ExamStage+AIS.1+Level.1+F+    (ExamStage|id), E4)
```

This was the output:

```
> summary(model6)
Linear mixed model fit by REML 
t-tests use  Satterthwaite approximations to degrees of freedom ['lmerMod']
Formula: MS_TOT ~ acstatus + ExamStage + acstatus * ExamStage + AIS.1 +      Level.1 + F + (ExamStage | id)
   Data: E4

REML criterion at convergence: 9776.9

Scaled residuals: 
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.8608 -0.3650 -0.0252  0.4319  3.3463 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr
 id       (Intercept) 150.346  12.2616      
          ExamStage     0.798   0.8933  0.09
 Residual              40.445   6.3597      
Number of obs: 1298, groups:  id, 451

Fixed effects:
                Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)          19.8213     1.4241 496.8000  13.919  < 2e-16 ***
acstatus1            -1.5927     1.7913 417.6000  -0.889  0.37445    
acstatus2            -0.7399     1.8835 422.9000  -0.393  0.69465    
ExamStage             3.0816     0.2133 768.4000  14.446  < 2e-16 ***
AIS.1B                4.1984     2.1890 436.6000   1.918  0.05578 .  
AIS.1C               16.3097     1.9329 440.3000   8.438 4.44e-16 ***
AIS.1D               50.0334     1.5282 444.9000  32.740  < 2e-16 ***
Level.1TL            24.6689     1.3098 443.1000  18.833  < 2e-16 ***
F                    -0.1745     0.0158 703.9000 -11.045  < 2e-16 ***
acstatus1:ExamStage   0.2134     0.1891 211.0000   1.128  0.26053    
acstatus2:ExamStage   0.5455     0.2042 207.7000   2.671  0.00816 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
        (Intr) acstt1 acstt2 ExmStg AIS.1B AIS.1C AIS.1D Lv.1TL F          ac1:ES
acstatus1   -0.215                                                               
acstatus2   -0.157  0.176                                                        
ExamStage   -0.260  0.009  0.018                                                 
AIS.1B      -0.382 -0.023 -0.008  0.005                                          
AIS.1C      -0.472 -0.035 -0.062  0.008  0.268                                   
AIS.1D      -0.648  0.014 -0.101  0.021  0.342  0.414                            
Level.1TL   -0.578 -0.009 -0.014  0.003  0.067  0.157  0.266                     
F            0.226  0.041  0.028 -0.888 -0.005 -0.007 -0.019 -0.002              
acstts1:ExS  0.054 -0.194 -0.050 -0.178 -0.003 -0.002 -0.007 -0.002 -0.069       
acstts2:ExS  0.047 -0.050 -0.192 -0.168  0.000  0.000 -0.001  0.001 -0.060  0.254
```

As you can see, the acstatus2*Time interaction was significant. So, I said that compared to acstatus0, acstatus2 cause a (0.5455*12)=5.88 greater increase over time to MS_TOT. However, my boss wants a measure of variance for this number- I have the standard error of the estimate, btu how would I get it for the estimate over a 12-month period?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look up how to calculate marginal effects.  For example, [How to calculate the standard error of the marginal effects in interactions?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/55795/126864)

Your statement

> compared to acstatus0, acstatus2 cause a (0.5455*12)=5.88 greater increase over time to MS_TOT

is not exactly correct, because we also need to include the main effect of `acstatus2`. The marginal effect of `acstatus2` is a function of time, so we might say that `acstatus2` is associated with a -0.7399 + 0.5455 * X increase in `MS_TOT`, where `X` represents months.

The variance of the marginal effect, `Var(a + bX)`, is `Var(a) + X^2 * Var(b) + 2 * X * Cov(a, b)` (where `X` in your case is 12).  We can extract these quantities -- `Var(a)`, `Var(b)`, and `Cov(a, b)` -- from the variance-covariance matrix of the fixed effects.  To get the standard error of the marginal effect of `acstatus2`, you might try something like

```
variables <- c("acstatus2", "acstatus2:ExamStage")
vcv <- vcov(model6)[variables, variables]
sqrt(vcv[1, 1] + 12^2 * vcv[2, 2] + 2 * 12 * vcv[1, 2])
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your quick reply!! and you are right, I did not include the main effect of acstatus2, as I should have specified that I am only interested in the time-interaction effect, and the standard error of that across a 12-month period. I'm sure your answer covers that as well, but could you possibly explain how to calculate just this variance?

Comment: If you are asking what is `Var(12 * b)`, then the answer is `12^2 * Var(b)`.  In standard error terms, you would just multiply the s.e. by 12.